# In the fundamental theorem of calculus, what does the area function find?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If we are talking about the fundamental theorem of calculus, then there is a point in the explanation where you have to assume that there is some area function that exists, $A(x)$, that will give us the area of everything to the left of the curve from $a$.

My question is does it give the area of everything between the line $x=a$ and the origin? Or does it give the area of everything to the left of the curve from $x=a$?

The confusion has come from the fact that I thought it was everything from the origin to the line, but then when you are finding the area bound by the curve $y=x^2$, and the lines $x=1$, and $x=-1$, why would you subtract the definite integrals at 1 and -1 from each other, rather than add them?

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus can be presented without the area function. It is best that you give some details of presentation in your book.

Comment: Also from your question I guess that the area function $A(x) $ is related to another function $f$ defined on $[a, b] $ such that $f(x) \geq 0$ and then $$A(x) = \text{ area of set }\{(p, q) \mid a\leq p\leq x, 0\leq q\leq f(p) \}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that definite integrals are sensitive to the orientation of the intervals: $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x) \, dx = -\int_b^a f(x) \, dx$.

So, when you integrate from $a$ to $b$, your direction matters. As a consequence, if you integrate a positive function in "negative direction" then you get the result of "negative area". To be more clear, let's consider your function $f(x)=x^2$ and $A(x) = \displaystyle \int_0^x t^2 \, dt$. If you integrate $f(x)$ "from $0$ to $-1$", $\displaystyle \int_0^{-1} x^2 \, dx$, then your result is equal to $-1$ times the area between the lines $x=-1$ and $x=0$ because your direction is negative.

That is $A(-1)=-\text{area}<0$.

On the other hand, If you integrate this function "from $0$ to $1$", $\displaystyle \int_0^{1} x^2 \, dx$, then your result is equal to the area between the lines $x=0$ and $x=1$ because your direction is positive.

That is $A(1)=\text{AREA}>0$.

Hence, to obtain the value of "total area" you need to sum the areas. That is, "Total Area" $ = $ AREA $+$ area and

AREA $+$ area $=$ AREA $-$ ($-$area) $ = A(1) - A(-1) \left( =\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1} x^2 \, dx \right)$.

Thus, we need to "subtract the definite integrals at $1$ and $-1$ from each other" to compansate adding negative areas.

Comment: This is super clear - thank you so much!

Comment: @harpomiel You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but:

One form of the fundamental theorem of calculus is that for a continuous $f:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$, the differential of its integral function $F(x) :=\int_a^x f$ is $F'(x) =f(x)$.

Thus if $a\le c<d\le b$, we have $\int_c^d f=\int_a^d f - \int_a^c f=F(d) - F(c)$.